# What is the purpose of `external` keyword in Kotlin?

Tags: java-native-interface, external, kotlin, keyword

What exactly is the purpose of the **`external`** keyword in Kotlin?

I guess it's for JNI like `native` in Java, but I can't seem to find any actual reference or documentation on this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Indeed, it's an equivalent of Java's `native`. It's currently missing from the documentation but there's an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11021) to add it.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks for the link to the issue

Comment: But at https://github.com/ligee/kotlin-ndk-samples/blob/master/hello-jni/src/com/example/hellojni/HelloJni.kt it uses native keyword ...

Comment: @AlexByrth unfortunately you can find plenty of GitHub repositories that contain outdated Kotlin code which no longer compiles with Kotlin 1.0

Comment: The issue linked by @yole has been fixed, as you'd expect after 6 years.

Answer (score 5):

According to documentation:
external marks a declaration as implemented not in Kotlin (accessible through JNI or in JavaScript)