# Kotlin replacement for javah

Tags: java, kotlin, java-native-interface

[`javah` has been deprecated since JDK 8 and will be/has been removed in JDK 10](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/313), and according to JEP 313 and the deprecation text, `javac` with the `-h` flag should be used instead:

> Warning: The `javah` tool is planned to be removed in the next major JDK release. The tool has been superseded by the '-h' option added to `javac` in JDK 8. Users are recommended to migrate to using the `javac` '-h' option; see the javac man page for more information.

The problem is, `javah` operates on compiled `.class` files, while `javac` operates on source files (i.e. `.java` files.)

`javah` works fine with Kotlin and [`external`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552834/what-is-the-purpose-of-external-keyword-in-kotlin) functions, since everything ends up compiled as Java bytecode, but since there aren't any Java source files when using Kotlin, I don't see any way `javac -h` could work.

Is there a `javah` replacement, or a workaround, for Kotlin?

Comment: IntelliJ can show you the bytecode for your Kotlin source, and can then also decompile that bytecode to Java source.  Can you then use that source with `javah`? (A bit clunky, I know ...)

Comment: http://www.owsiak.org/how-to-solve-missing-javah-ugly-way/

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [gjavah](https://github.com/Glavo/gjavah).
In the future I will also implement an easier-to-use command line tool which provides similar functionality to javah.

Comment: The library with tag `0.2.0` seems to failed the build in jitpack. And `0.1.1` doesn't has any Main method, so basically there's no way to integrate it with gradle. Lemme know if have any plans for further updates?

Answer (score 4):

I've wrote a simple gradle task for generating JNI headers, its similar approach as the one posted by @Oo.oO but has a better integration with gradle and hence can be run on Windows as well as Unix based OS.

```kotlin
val generateJniHeaders by tasks.creating {
    group = "build"
    dependsOn(tasks.getByName("compileKotlinJvm"))

    // For caching
    inputs.dir("src/jvmMain/kotlin")
    outputs.dir("src/jvmMain/generated/jni")

    doLast {
        val javaHome = Jvm.current().javaHome
        val javap = javaHome.resolve("bin").walk().firstOrNull { it.name.startsWith("javap") }?.absolutePath ?: error("javap not found")
        val javac = javaHome.resolve("bin").walk().firstOrNull { it.name.startsWith("javac") }?.absolutePath ?: error("javac not found")
        val buildDir = file("build/classes/kotlin/jvm/main")
        val tmpDir = file("build/tmp/jvmJni").apply { mkdirs() }

        val bodyExtractingRegex = """^.+\Rpublic \w* ?class ([^\s]+).*\{\R((?s:.+))\}\R$""".toRegex()
        val nativeMethodExtractingRegex = """.*\bnative\b.*""".toRegex()

        buildDir.walkTopDown()
            .filter { "META" !in it.absolutePath }
            .forEach { file ->
                if (!file.isFile) return@forEach

                val output = ByteArrayOutputStream().use {
                    project.exec {
                        commandLine(javap, "-private", "-cp", buildDir.absolutePath, file.absolutePath)
                        standardOutput = it
                    }.assertNormalExitValue()
                    it.toString()
                }

                val (qualifiedName, methodInfo) = bodyExtractingRegex.find(output)?.destructured ?: return@forEach

                val lastDot = qualifiedName.lastIndexOf('.')
                val packageName = qualifiedName.substring(0, lastDot)
                val className = qualifiedName.substring(lastDot+1, qualifiedName.length)

                val nativeMethods =
                        nativeMethodExtractingRegex.findAll(methodInfo).mapNotNull { it.groups }.flatMap { it.asSequence().mapNotNull { group -> group?.value } }.toList()
                if (nativeMethods.isEmpty()) return@forEach

                val source = buildString {
                    appendln("package $packageName;")
                    appendln("public class $className {")
                    for (method in nativeMethods) {
                        if ("()" in method) appendln(method)
                        else {
                            val updatedMethod = StringBuilder(method).apply {
                                var count = 0
                                var i = 0
                                while (i < length) {
                                    if (this[i] == ',' || this[i] == ')') insert(i, " arg${count++}".also { i += it.length + 1 })
                                    else i++
                                }
                            }
                            appendln(updatedMethod)
                        }
                    }
                    appendln("}")
                }
                val outputFile = tmpDir.resolve(packageName.replace(".", "/")).apply { mkdirs() }.resolve("$className.java").apply { delete() }.apply { createNewFile() }
                outputFile.writeText(source)

                project.exec {
                    commandLine(javac, "-h", jniHeaderDirectory.absolutePath, outputFile.absolutePath)
                }.assertNormalExitValue()
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no built-in way to do this. There is [an open issue for this on the Kotlin issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-35127) that was raised in November 2019, but as of now it has not been prioritized and doesn't have a target version.

The only way to produce the header with JDK 10+ is to use `javac -h`, which only works for Java source code, not Kotlin. I tested the method in [How to solve missing javah in Java 10 – ugly way](https://www.owsiak.org/how-to-solve-missing-javah-ugly-way/) linked by Oo.oO, and it works as a workaround for now. The steps are:

1. Use `javap` to decompile the bytecode back into Java
2. Edit the decompiled Java to make it suitable for producing the header file (reducing the file to just the `native` method definitions).
3. Run the decompiled Java code through `javac -h` to produce the header

I'm thinking of writing a gradle script to do this (or hoping somebody else beats me to it!). If I manage to get it done, I'll update this post.

Comment: Did you made a script/plugin? I need one :p, the most upvoted answer is outdated its artifact is not built properly, I don't think I'll fork it rn anyway...

Comment: No, sorry. I eventually gave up on JNI and ended up calling a separate process instead. :(

Answer (score 2):

Until Kotlin starts generating JDK10-specific bytecode, you can use `javah` tool from JDK 9 or lower on the compiled kotlin classes.

And even after that you can compile `external` functions with `jvmTarget=1.8` and use `javah` on the resulting classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make it using `javap` and creating facade classes based on `class` files.

Take a look here for a sample: http://www.owsiak.org/how-to-solve-missing-javah-ugly-way/