# Unable to generate header file in Java 10 using javah

Tags: java, java-native-interface, java-10

> Hi All,
>
> While migrating from Java 8 to Java 10 , I came accross a strange
>   issue. In our legacy system there is a JNI layer and we are generating
>   the header file from a .class file using the below command like:

```
javah -jni -classpath classes -o jpdm.h com.osm.biz.pdm
```

> This set of command is giving me the issue like:
>
> Error: Could not find class file for 'com.osm.biz.pdm'.
>
> I am getting this perticular issue while compiling in JAVA 10.
>
> Strange thing is when I replace the same .class file (pdm.java) built
>   in Java 8 and execute the same command as above , I don't get any
>   issue.
>
> My question
>
> 1. Is Java 10 no more support header file generation through above command ?
> 2. Is there any alternative way to generate header file creation using Java 10?

Comment: Seems like javah is not available for JDK10: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506237/generate-jni-header-files-for-class-files-in-jdk-10?rq=1

Comment: Anywork around?

Comment: javah was removed in JDK 10, the recommend way since JDK 8 is to generate header file has been with "javac -h".

Comment: But we can't apply this for a .class file.

Comment: I am trying to create a header file with name jpdm.h . This header file is created through a python script. Any way I can use something like this?javac -h -classpath  jpdm.h  com.osm.biz.pdm.java. But it is not working.